# Determine Network Interfaces in Java

Tags: java, networking, network-interface

I'm trying to find a reasonable way to acquire network interfaces within Java according to the following needs;

1. Need to be able to filter interfaces connected through VPN.
2. Need to be able to filter Virtual interfaces. This is mostly needed when the application is run at virtual machines.
3. Need to be able to filter sub-interfaces. By this, I'm not sure if sub-interface is the correct keyword here but when the application is run with the parameter "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true", I get more interfaces than usual from NetworkInterface class in Java. Following is an example;

- Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz
- Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz-WFP Native MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000
- Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz-Virtual WiFi Filter Driver-0000
- Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz-Native WiFi Filter Driver-0000

In short, what I need to acquire is just the actual WiFi/Ethernet interfaces.

What I have tried so far;

1. I tried to filter with networkInterface.isVirtual() and networkInterface.isLoopback() methods but those were not enough to eliminate sub-interfaces and VPNs.
2. I tried to filter the remaining with some String filtering from interface's display names like eliminating the ones without "WiFi" or "Ethernet" keyword, which I hoped to help with getting rid of VPNs. Unfortunately, when this code is run in virtual machines(Windows/Linux), I see that interface names do not include these keywords.

So, is there a good way to acquire only the main WiFi and Ethernet interfaces without having to worry the run time environment (whether it be Windows, Linux or VM)?